# Bind list element to tap JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a function that renders a simple list using JQuery Mobile.

```
function() {
    var view = $("#test-content");
    view.empty();
    console.log(view);
    var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(view);

    for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $("<li id=\"item" + i + "\">Item " + i + "</li>").appendTo(ul);
    }
    ul.listview();
}
```

How do I bind each element such that when it is tapped, it changes themes?

I tried adding the following code in the for loop, but it doesn't do anything.

```
$("#item" + i).bind("tap", function() {
            $(this).attr("data-theme", "e"); 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the # for id selector also ensure the element with id item are added before binding event.

```
$("#item" + i).bind("tap", function() {
        $(this).attr("data-theme", "e");     
});
```

You may use on() for dynamically added elements. You can delegate the event to parent of dynamically added elements or to `document`.

```
$(document).on("tap", "id^=item", function() {
     $(this).attr("data-theme", "e"); 
});
```

Comment: Oops, good catch. However, even after the #, my list elements still don't react to being clicked.

I'll also be sure to use the on() method for problems like this, thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you still see any way to fix my code I'd be grateful for the help!  My list elements still don't react to the tap event.

Comment: Never mind, it seems that I can't set the id in the <li> element, I have to make a div element within the li that keeps track of the element's id.